# Playing a video using VLC

Tags: raspbian, video, vlc

I have a model B Pi and have installed the newest version of VLC. When I try to play a ten-second video file (.avi format) the VLC window opens with the orange logo then after few seconds it turns all black and the window is closed automatically. What may be causing this and how do I solve it? Alternatively are there any suggestions for another video player to try?

Answer (score 4):

Use `omxplayer` which is already installed on the Pi and performs much better, because it uses the GPU. It is actually the core of the RASPBMC Media Centre.

NOTE `omxplayer` runs from the command line.

Comment: +1, newer builds have support for subtitles and multiple audio streams. In my experience, it plays most .mkvs without a hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/brainfoolong/omxwebgui-v2

Above is the link so that you could have a Graphical User Interface (GUI) with OMXplayer. Wonderful!!